# How to get mock utility function with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have react module which calls function from utility. I’m testing the component and mocking utility function but somehow I’m not getting the line coverage for it. I mocked utility function to get the test wrong but it’s still passing making me wonder there’s something fishy going on.

Any tips or guides on how to mock utility function?

```
//Utils.js
export const add = () => {
    return x;
}
```

`add` function is used in module App. I want to test App but mock doesnt return what I am expecting it to return.

```
//Mocking as below
jest.mock('../utils', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('../utils'),
    add:() => 4
}));
```

Comment: Provide the code you want to test

Answer (score 9):

You can use `jest.spyOn` to make a stub for `utils.add` method.

E.g.

`App.js`:

```js
import * as utils from './Utils';

export function bootstrap() {
  return utils.add();
}
```

`Utils.js`:

```js
export const add = () => {
  const x = 1;
  return x;
};
```

`App.test.js`:

```js
import { bootstrap } from './App';
import * as utils from './Utils';

describe('bootstrap', () => {
  it('should mock utils.add method correctly', () => {
    const addStub = jest.spyOn(utils, 'add').mockReturnValueOnce(2);
    const actual = bootstrap();
    expect(actual).toBe(2);
    expect(addStub).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    addStub.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(utils.add()).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/59208419/App.test.js (7.993s)
  bootstrap
    ✓ should mock utils.add method correctly (5ms)
    ✓ should pass (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 App.js   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 Utils.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.072s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59208419